# Why do I get the right object in the flask template but a bunch of Numbers in the click function?

Tags: javascript, flask

I am developing an article comment using flask. However, When I tested the commentIp object from flask by the click handler function,I got a string of Numbers instead of objects.

This is template code.(cips:An array of cip objects；I get the correct object in template)

```
  {% for i in range(0,comments |length) %}
      {% set comment=comments[i] %}
      <p>{{ loop.index }}. Email:{{ comment.email }}</p>
      <p>PostTime:{{ comment.postTime }}</p>
      <p>Content:{{ comment.content }}</p>

      {% set up_btn_id='up_btn'~ i|string %}
      {% set down_btn_id='down_btn'~ i|string %}

      {% if cips[i].vote_state ==0 %}
          <button id='{{up_btn_id}}' onclick="upVote(this)">up:{{ comment.upvoteNum }}</button>
          <button id="{{down_btn_id}}" onclick="downVote(this)">down:{{ comment.downvoteNum }}</button>

      {% elif cips[i].vote_state ==1 %}
          <button id='{{up_btn_id}}' onclick="upVote(this)" style="color: green">up:{{ comment.upvoteNum }}</button>
          <button id="{{down_btn_id}}" onclick="downVote(this)">down:{{ comment.downvoteNum }}</button>

      {% else %}
          <button id='{{up_btn_id}}' onclick="upVote(this)">up:{{ comment.upvoteNum }}</button>
          <button id="{{down_btn_id}}" onclick="downVote(this)" style="color: red">down:{{ comment.downvoteNum }}</button>
      {% endif %}


      {% if flag==1 %}
          <form action="../cdelete/{{ comment.id }}" method="post">
              Password:<input type="password" name="psw">
              <input type="submit" value="delete">
          </form>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Here is upVote function

```
 function upVote(up_btn) {
        const cips = '{{cips}}';
        for (let cip in cips)
            console.log(cip);//a bunch of Numbers from 0 to 72
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the value is placed into a template its taking the literal values. The array of `cips` cannot be understood by javascript. Think about it, it's a list of objects you've defined in python - how is javascript supposed to know what those are? It works for your values like `comment.upvoteNum` because that's a literal value. It doesn't understand those objects - you're likely seeing the object memory address. So in order to get your {{cips}} into an array in javascript you need to convert those objects to `json`. Flask has some handy functions for this - check out `tojson` - its HTML safe as well as json safe. It also looks like you're trying to update the state of the models you passed in (i.e. upvote). You probably want that submitted to the flask view functions, so keep in mind that the changes made the cip objects in the HTML are just that. Unless sent back to your server and processed, they won't be reflected in your cip models in python.